# Quartz and Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, quartz

I am trying to use Quartz with Quarkus.
In the guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/quartz

They create an application scoped TaskBean, that creates a job instance, that when executed
does nothing but persisting an empty Task entity.

This IMHO doesn't look very clean and doesn't help much either a far as I understand it.
I am rather trying to follow a more default setup of Quartz - so I have create a "classical" Job that is supposed to do the work - and I added this to the scheduler. All working fine. Now I just need to inject a service into this job, something similar to:
http://vijaykiran.com/2013/01/a-quick-way-to-integrate-seam3-cdi-and-quartz-jobs/

Has anyone here possibly done this for Quarkus before?

Answer (score 1):

At this point, Quarkus does not support injection into Quartz Jobs - based on my request a patch is on the way. In the meantime, you can directly retrieve an instance from Arc like this:  Arc.container().instance(YourClass.class).get();